# Could someone explain this paragraph?

Tags: wavefunction, superconductivity

> "Although Arnold Sommerfeld’s theories had used quantum mechanics, his focus had been on the probability of the electron distribution. The phases of the individual wavefunctions had been ignored. However, that appeared to be very sensible since it was reasoned that they would all be different and all the possible interference effects would surely cancel out. It turned out that
>   although this is normally true, in a superconductor the phases of the wavefunctions do not all randomly cancel out."
>
> (Superconductivity - Very short instroduction by Stephen J. Blundell)

- The sentence "all the possible interference effects would surely cancel out" should explain why "The phases of the individual wavefunctions had been ignored". However, I don't understand how it can explain, more clearly how the total combined wavefunction which is cancelled out can explain for ignorance of phases of individual wavefunctions. 
  Is there any interference in Sommerfeld’s theories? (Drude-Sommerfeld's theory of conductivity in metals)
- "phases of the wavefunctions do not all randomly cancel out". What does "randomly" mean?. And could "phases of wavefuctions" cancel?, it should be "wavefuctions".

Comment: I think it refers to the fact that phases appear as additive constants  within sines and cosines in complex wavefunctions. If these are assumed random the amount of positive interference terms to that of negative interference terms will cancel. It is only with fixed phases that interference terms appear. It should be "the effect of the random phases of the wavefunction" cancel.

Comment: Yes I can explain the paragraph. If you want me to do so, please change the title of your question !

Answer (score 1):

The statement seems to refer to *coherence*. When the different wave functions have fixed relative phase relationships to each other, one would see interference effects. On the other hand, if there is a process that somehow "mixes" the relative phases so that the relative phase becomes unpredictable, then the wave functions would add incoherently. Then one can ignore the phase. Being unpredictable, the phase of the wave function would change "randomly."

An analogy would be to think how one would create incoherent light when given a coherent source of light. One way is to pass the light through a spinning ground glass plate. In this case the spinning glass plate corresponds to the different "possible interference effects." The result is a randomly changing relative phase between any two points in the beam.

The last part of the paragraph, which states that the phase cannot be ignored complete would then imply that the wavefunctions are not completely incoherent, but that some remnant of coherence remains.